# testing foursquare API at the localhost

Tags: api, foursquare

I am testing the foursquare API at the localhost

in the configuration of foursquare developer, I set the application url as

Download / welcome page url
**`http://localhost`**
Your privacy policy url
**`http://localhost/`**
Callback url
**`http://localhost/app`**

my application url is `http://localhost/app`, and the idea is really simple, use HTML5 geo API to get my geo location, and use this geo data to get nearby places from foursquare API.

However, when the page redirect the foursquare at the auth, the redirected page says something goes wrong.

I guess it is because of the callback url, could somebody show me how to set right configuration at the localhost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this issue. It appears that when authorizing, the 4SQ API expects the redirect_uri to sent and to match what is in the APP settings. So basically, when creating the Auth URL you should be sending the client_id, response_type AND redirect_uri. The value you put for your redirect_uri MUST match what you entered in your APP settings which in your case would be "http://localhost/app"